# Why would I ever want to use Maybe instead of a List?

Tags: list, haskell, types, option-type

Seeing as the Maybe type is isomorphic to the set of null and singleton lists, why would anyone ever want to use the Maybe type when I could just use lists to accomodate absence?

Comment: One place to look for potential motivations as to why we care about distinguishing isomorphic types is why people use and care about `newtype`.

Comment: I would ask "why would you use a list when you just need a `Maybe`?" `Maybe` is more specific and many errors are prevented because you can't even write the erroneous code. It also makes your intent more clear in type signatures. I can't really think of a benefit off the top of my head of using a list in a situation where you could use a `Maybe` (except maybe as a very brief intermediate form). What prompted the question?

Comment: One example of using a list in place of `Maybe` is in the book "Programming in Haskell", where it is shown how to implement a `Parser` monad from scratch (similar to `ReadP`), and it has a type of `String -> [(a, String)]`, which is perculiar because the list is only ever empty or a singleton. No idea why this is done, just giving an example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building on existing (and correct) answers, I'll mention a *typeclass* based answer.

**Different types convey different intentions** - returning a `Maybe a` represents a computation with the possiblity of failing while `[a]` could represent non-determinism (or, in simpler terms, multiple possible return values).

This plays into the fact that different types have different instances for typeclasses - and these instances cater to the underlying essence the type conveys. Take [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html) and its operator `(<|>)` which represents what it means to combine (or choose) between arguments given.

- **`Maybe a`** Combining computations that can fail just means taking the first that is not `Nothing`
- **`[a]`** Combining two computations that each had multiple return values just means concatenating together all possible values.

Then, depending on which types your functions use, `(<|>)` would behave differently. Of course, you could argue that you don't need `(<|>)` or anything like that, but then you are missing out on one of Haskell's main strengths: it's many high-level combinator libraries.

As a general rule, we like our types to be as snug fitting and intuitive as possible. That way, we are not fighting the standard libraries and our code is more readable.

Comment: As a concrete example, `Just x <|> Just y == Just x`, but `[x] <|> [y] == [x, y]`.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an ideal example, since these behave similarly if (like the OP) you only pay attention to the head of the list. The example I'm thinking of now is `Monoid`, but that's a poor example because the `Monoid (Maybe a)` instance was designed wrong.

Comment: @dfeuer Yeah, the example could be better. I couldn't think of anything else simple enough (`Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad` behave the same way and `Monoid` also requires another `Monoid`). If you have a better idea, please comment it!

Answer (score 14):

Because if you match a list against the patterns `[]` and `[x]` that's not an exhaustive match and you'll get a warning about that, forcing you to either add another case that'll never get called or to ignore the warning.

Matching a `Maybe` against `Nothing` and `Just x` however is exhaustive. So you'll only get a warning if you fail to match one of those cases.

If you choose your types such that they can only represent values that you may actually produce, you can rely on non-exhaustiveness warnings to tell you about bugs in your code where you forget to check for a given a case. If you choose more "permissive" types, you'll always have to think about whether a warning represents an actual bug or just an impossible case.

Comment: Yes, you are at full liberty to disregard the warning and use "assignments"  with non-exhaustive patterns (can't call them functions/maps if they aren't exhaustive over the domain). The situations in which you would use a Maybe type, however, are those (from what I've seen) in which it is either easy or effortless to guarantee that using non-map assignments won't get you in trouble.

Comment: That said, I am still a budding haskeller so my experiences are possibly merely not yet extended to such problematic situations

Comment: @Tshimanga while you *can* disregard those warnings, it's often useful to write functions which are total over their domain, especially when writing something with a publicly-facing API (e.g. a package); `Maybe` helps with writing semantically meaningful code to achieve this, among other things.

Answer (score 11):

You should strive to have accurate types. *Maybe* expresses that there is exactly one value or that there is none. Many imperative languages represent the "none" case by the value *null*.

If you chose a list instead of *Maybe*, all your functions would be faced with the possibility that they get a list with more than one member. Probably many of them would only be defined for one value, and would have to fail on a pattern match. By using *Maybe*, you avoid a class of runtime errors entirely.

Answer (score 5):

Lisp, Scheme, Python, Ruby, JavaScript, etc., manage to get along with just one type each, which you could represent in Haskell with a big sum type. Every function handling a JavaScript (or whatever) value must be prepared to receive a number, a string, a function, a piece of the document object model, etc., and throw an exception if it gets something unexpected. People who program in typed languages like Haskell prefer to limit the number of unexpected things that can occur. They also like to express *ideas* using types, making types useful (and machine-checked) documentation. The closer the types come to representing the intended meaning, the more useful they are.

Comment: My thoughts, precisely.

Answer (score 3):

Because there are an infinite number of possible lists, and a finite number of possible values for the Maybe type. It perfectly represents one thing or the absence of something without any other possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Several answers have mentioned exhaustiveness as a factor here.  I think it is a factor, but not the biggest one, because there is a way to consistently treat lists as if they were `Maybe`s, which the `listToMaybe` function illustrates:

```
listToMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a
listToMaybe [] = Nothing
listToMaybe (a:_) = Just a
```

That's an exhaustive pattern match, which rules out any straightforward errors.

The factor I'd highlight as bigger is that by using the type that more precisely models the behavior of your code, you eliminate potential behaviors that would be possible if you used a more general alternative.  Say for example you have some context in your code where you uses a type of the form `a -> [b]`, though the only correct alternatives (given your program's specification) are empty or singleton lists.  Try as hard as you may to enforce the convention that this context should obey that rule, it's still possible that you'll mess up and:

1. Somehow a function used in that context will produce a list of two or more items;
2. And somehow a function that uses the results produced in that context will observe whether the lists have two or more items, and behave incorrectly in that case.

   - Example: some code that expects there to be no more than one value will blindly print the contents of the list and thus print multiple items when only one was supposed to be.

But if you use `Maybe`, then there really must be either one value or none, and the compiler enforces this.

Answer (score 0):

Even though isomorphic, e.g. QuickCheck will run slower because of the increase in search space.